# Basic Assembly Program

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I want to write my first assembly program. I have done some programs on papers but its my first time with the compiler. I am using [ideone](http://ideone.com). My program is very simple,
Translate `A = 5 - A` to Assembly

```
NEG A
ADD A, 5
```

Now I want to run this program and check it. How do I do it with the compiler? Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Why processor is this assembly for?

Comment: start using emu8086, it will be easier to programm in assembly for the 8086

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not quite valid 8086 assembly language.  At least, it's not in any assembly syntax that i'm aware of.

- For one thing, 8086 registers' names have two letters (they're named AX, BX, CX, DX, BP, SP, SI, and DI..plus some semi-special "segment registers" that can't be used for math).
- If that `A` is a memory location, you need a label for it somewhere.  And you need to let the assembler know that it's supposed to be a word pointer, since you're not putting it in a register.  (The register size can make the pointer semantics obvious, but you're not using registers here.  :P)

The corresponding 8086 code (which is quite similar) would be

```
neg ax
add ax, 5
```

Or, for memory:

```
neg  word [A]
add  word [A], 5

... other stuff here ...
A: resw 1             ; some assemblers say this; others say `dw ?`
```

(MASM can sometimes do without the brackets.  I don't know MASM syntax, so hopefully someone else can clear that part up.  Oh, and it's not the way pretty much every other assembler does things.  :P )

Now, with that, you'd need an assembler (like [Yasm](http://yasm.tortall.net/)) to turn that code into an executable.  (You'd need more code, though.  What you have here, won't run correctly as is.  At the very least, you need a `ret` at the end so that the CPU doesn't run off the rails.)  You could conceivably use a compiler and embed everything in an `__asm` block (or your compiler's equivalent), but you generally wouldn't do that if you're writing in pure assembly language.  That's kinda like using a sledgehammer to pound in nails.

Comment: Just for completeness : `res(b|w|d|q)` is used to declare uninitialized data (in the `.bss` section), while `d(b|w|d|q)` - initialized data in `.data`. :)

Comment: @Daniel: Some assemblers (MASM/TASM?) use `d[bwdq]` to declare uninitialized data as well.  Their `db ?` is much like others' `resb 1`.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem like the site you provided can run this code, as it sets a specific language. Assembly is not a language but a series of processor instructions. Download a 8086 emulator to run it.